# Disable rotation on a UISnapBehavior?

Tags: animation, ios7, uikit, uikit-dynamics

I like that `UISnapBehavior` snippet, but I really want to use it to slide in **one direction only** with a slight oscillation.

**Is there a way to turn off rotation for this behavior?**
As `SpriteKit` has `allowsRotation` property which can be easily turned off.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this by adding a `UIDynamicItemBehavior` to your `UIDynamicAnimator` and then setting its `allowsRotation` property to `NO` like so:

```
UIDynamicItemBehavior * dynamicItem = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.viewToSnap]];
dynamicItem.allowsRotation = NO;
[self.animator addBehavior:dynamicItem];
```

Comment: Agreed, this is the technique for stopping rotation in a `UISnapBehavior`. And if you have other UIKit Dynamics behaviors in place that you need to honor (e.g. `UICollisionBehavior`), then this is the right answer, as the `animateWithDuration` suggested elsewhere will not honor other behaviors you might have in place.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a better answer: A UISnapBehavior has an action property, which takes a block which gets called at every step.  Setting this block like this...

```
snapBehavior.action = ^{ view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; };
```

... causes the rotation to be nulled without any other side effects.

Answer (score 10):

**No need for `UIKitDynamics`** for this.

Just simply had to use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.65
          initialSpringVelocity:0.5
                        options:0
                     animations:^
    {
        self.transform = (self.expanded) ? self.openedTransition : self.closedTransition;
    }
                      completion:nil];
```

Comment: Agreed, if all you want is the spring effect, this is a simpler approach than using UIKit Dynamics.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same solution myself, but setting `allowsRotation` on a `UIDynamicItemBehavior` didn't quite give me the effect I was looking for.

I was able to prevent any movement from `UISnapBehavior` by placing using `UICollisionBehavior` and placing two boundaries on either side of the view I didn't want to move (in my case, I configured boundaries on left and right side of the view to prevent x-axis movement). To get a nice bouncy effect I also set `friction` to 0 (using `UIDynamicItemBehavior`) and adjusted the `damping` on `UISnapBehavior` to get the right amount of bounce.

Here's an example of what worked for me:

```
[self.animator removeAllBehaviors];

UISnapBehavior *snapBackBehavior = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.snappingView snapToPoint:self.slidePanelCenter];
snapBackBehavior.damping = 0.2;
[self.animator addBehavior:snapBackBehavior];

UIDynamicItemBehavior *itemBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.snappingView]];
itemBehavior.friction = 0.0;
[self.animator addBehavior:itemBehavior];

CGPoint leftBoundaryStart  = CGPointMake(self.snappingView.frame.origin.x, 0.0);
CGPoint leftBoundaryEnd    = CGPointMake(leftBoundaryStart.x, self.view.bounds.size.height);
CGPoint rightBoundaryStart = CGPointMake(leftBoundaryStart.x + self.snappingView.frame.size.width, 0.0);
CGPoint rightBoundaryEnd   = CGPointMake(rightBoundaryStart.x, leftBoundaryEnd.y);

UICollisionBehavior *collisionBehavior = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.snappingView]];
[collisionBehavior addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"leftEdge" fromPoint:leftBoundaryStart toPoint:leftBoundaryEnd];
[collisionBehavior addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"rightEdge" fromPoint:rightBoundaryStart toPoint:rightBoundaryEnd];
[self.animator addBehavior:collisionBehavior];
```

Answer (score 0):

UIView conforms to UIDynamicItem, which has a transform property that gets called when a rotation is made.  So overriding setTransform: with nothingness...

```
- (void)setTransform:(CGAffineTransform)transform
{
}
```

... stops the rotation, but probably with unknown and undesirable side effects.  Need some way to check if the dynamic animation is in progress.

There will still be some bouncy motion parallel to the direction of movement on the way to the new location.

It would be great if we could control the amount of the rotation/bouncy effect as it's quite cartoonish as is.